# How Can I Change The Value Positions Assigned To A List In Python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

If I have the following code:

```
sentence = input("Enter Your Sentence: ")
sentencelist = sentence.split()
```

Presume that the user entered the sentence `"Welcome To StackOverflow"`, this would then be converted to a list by the code above. If I indexed the list for the word `"Welcome"`, Python would say that the position of this word is `0`.

How do I alter the list so that the first word in a list is in position `1`?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Python lists use 0-based index. So you can't really do that without adding another item at the beginning.

```
>>> s = "Welecome To StackOverflow"
>>> words = s.split()
>>> words
['Welecome', 'To', 'StackOverflow']
>>> words[0]
'Welecome'
>>> words.insert(0, '')
>>> words[1]
'Welecome'
>>> " ".join(words)
' Welecome To StackOverflow'
>>>
```

So while this works, this is an ugly solution - something we should NOT do. Please use the 0-based index.